# IE 7 & 8 Object doesn't support this property or method message with function call

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I get the following error message in IE 8 & 7, with the following code, specifically when I call the function:

```
setDayDelay();
```

What could be wrong here?

```
function setDayDelay() {    
    if (twoDigitDate == 1) {              
           day = ("day1");
           startbuttondelay = 1600;
    } else if (twoDigitDate == 7) {
           day = ("day7");
           startbuttondelay = 9400;
    } else if (twoDigitDate == 8) {
           day = ("day8");
           startbuttondelay = 10300;
    } else if (twoDigitDate == 9) {
           day = ("day9");
           startbuttondelay = 11000;
    } else {
           day = ("inactive");
           startbuttondelay = 1000;
    }

    console.log("The day variable is: " + day);
    console.log("The startbutton delay is: " + startbuttondelay);   
}

setDayDelay();
```

Comment: There's no console in IE7 and if you don't have dev tools open in IE8, there's no console there either. Try using alerts to test in IE7 first.

Comment: `I get the following error message in IE 8 & 7` What error msg? `day = ("day1");` Not sure about enclosing var values in `()`

Comment: I removed those brackets but still get the console error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is twoDigitDate a global variable or undefined in your code ?
What does the "error message" say ?

Comment: this was the problem, the day variable wasn't declared as global. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

### Declare `twoDigitDate` variable somewhere before using it.

[Try this out](http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/2sYJM/), this works on IE7 and IE8.